# Remove the default satellite and map label

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to remove in Google map the default satellite and map label which is located in the right side corner.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? Can you share you attempt? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls?csw=1)

Look at **Adding Controls to the Map** part, you have to tell in your map options which control you want to display on the map. You just have not to add the control you don't want, in your case `mapTypeControl`

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: /*your zoom*/,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(/*your LatLng*/),
    mapTypeControl: false
    /*Some other options*/
}
```